# Creating a MySQL connection on NetBeans (Mac OS)

Tags: mysql, netbeans-8, database-connection

I am new to both NetBeans and MySQL.

I am trying to establish a new database connection to MySQL in Netbeans (8.2), using the 'New Connection Wizard'.

However, after inserting the correct username (root) and password details, I am receiving the following error message:

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long)

Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same a few hours ago. You have to change the JDBC MySQL driver (5.1.46):

1. Download it from the [MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html).
2. On the '*Services*' tab, expand '*Databases*' then right click on the '***Drivers***' folder and choose '***New driver***'.
3. Add the ***.jar*** file (*mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar*) you just downloaded and give it a name as you want.

Once you've done that, try to connect again using that driver ;-)

Let me know if it worked out for you !

Comment: As of Sep'20, download the latest one i.e `mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar`. It worked.

Comment: in windows `import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;` then how about in mac ? i still unresolved on `Connection` because dunno

Answer (score 0):

To Install **MySQL** JBDC Driver in **Netbeans 12.3 (Mac OS)** follow the below steps.

1. **Download** JDBC Driver from **MySQL Official site** [from here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

2. There you have to select the Operating system as '**Platform Independent**' for Mac OS.
3. You can choose to Download either **tar.gz or zip** file
4. Extract it and place the jar file on a safe & specific location (*I have placed it in /Applications/ Directory to avoid its getting deleted by Mistake*)
5. Go to Netbeans, Open Services tab.

> To open Service Tab you can use Shortcut ⌘+5.

6. Expand '**Databases**'
7. To update existing MySQL JDBC Driver

> Right-Click on the '**Drivers**' directory >> Right Click on MySQL (Connector/J driver) >> Click '**Customize**' >> Click '**Add**' >> Select '**.jar**' >> Click '**OK**'

9. To Add New MySQL JDBC Driver

> Right-Click on the '**Drivers**' directory >> Click New Driver >> Click '**Add**' >> Select '**.jar**' >> Click '**OK**'

10. It's Done. You are ready to Use MySQL Driver